# Strange difference between $(element).width() and its actual width in pixel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page with just an element in it. I have to set the width of this element in mm, but I need its width in pixel later. I've set the width using css code like:

```
width:50mm
```

and get the width after a while with

```
$(element).width()
```

which gives me 189 as result. Then I press "Print Screen" button on keyboard and paste the clipboard content in image editor and strangely its width is 252px!

I'm curious why is those values that far away from each other?

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/k9w1fz0k/

Comment: Use your browser developer tools to get the actual layout of the element. You posted no code so it's going to be hard for anybody to provide specific help.

Comment: I didn't think that was important but added the fiddle link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an element has padding or a border, the padding will not be considered in the "layout width" of the element (returned by $(element).width()), but will increase the visual size of the element. The reason for this is because width is a CSS property of the element, not a calculated one.

```css
#foo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

#bar {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">foo</div>
<div id="bar">bar</div>
```

Comment: You can use `outerWidth()` in that case though.

Comment: Yup, and you can get it in vanilla JS too using element.offsetWidth.